# Throughput & Latency of Blockchain/DLT platforms

Tags: blockchain, corda, corda-dlt

**Throughput**: the number of successful transactions per second. A workload can be 
**Latency**: the response time per transaction i.e. time for one transaction to finish before starting another.

Researched a lot on the internet but have got information only on hyperledger and ethereum.

What is throughput (TX/Sec) and latency(Sec) for platforms such as Hyperledger, Ethereum, Corda, Ripple, Quorum, Chain, Openchain, Multichain, Stellar, and Strato

Comment: And wich are the values of the Throughput and the Latency for Hyperledger and Ethereum? Could you copy them?

Comment: Consider both on an average and do not take it at face value. Hyperledger throughput: 1273 Tx/sec , Latency: 51 Sec. Ethereum throughput : 284 Tx/sec and latency 114 sec

Answer (score 0):

Corda has not published official performance numbers as of yet. See https://www.corda.net/2017/12/dlt-performance-considerations/ for a discussion of Corda's performance.